# Subquery in the FROM clause?

Tags: mysql

This query correctly joins my two tables. I then want to use this newly formed table in another query as a subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM players s JOIN player_data t
WHERE s.player_id = t.player_id

Is it possible to do smth like this:

SELECT MAX(e.height)
FROM (SELECT *
FROM players s JOIN player_data t
WHERE s.player_id = t.player_id) as e
GROUP BY e.height
```

Comment: Have your tried to execute the query?

Comment: You can happily use a sub query like that. However your example doesn't make sense as you are using an aggregate function (MAX) on the same field that you GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.check documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html)

you have to use `as` clause for subquery result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use subquery for that.

```
SELECT max(t.height) or max(s.height) depends on where's the height fields is
FROM players s JOIN player_data t
WHERE s.player_id = t.player_id
```

If you can provide sample data it will be good.

Comment: I wanted try it as a subquery.

Comment: Ok then you can do it. Just a note, sub query is a little bit slower.